# How do I join only sets that have common elements between them recursively while leaving all others sets as is?

Tags: python, set

Let's say I have a list of sets defined as follows

```
set_list = [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 50, 60}, {70, 90}, {70, 80}, {1, 2}, {999, 888}]
```

I want to define a function that receives a list of sets such as the above and outputs a new list of sets such that if the above list is passed as an argument the output will be as follows

```
output = [{1, 2, 3, 50, 60}, {70, 80, 90}, {999, 888}]
```

How can I go about implementing something like this?

Note that I am using a list out of convenience (I don't care about the order of the sets but  I do want the output to not contain duplicates) since sets can't be elements of sets. I know I can use frozensets, but it is cumbersome to write. Nevertheless, any implementation using frozensets or otherwise will be great.

Comment: You forgot to attach your attempts to solve it.

Comment: I suggest that you start by working some examples by hand. What steps do you take to solve the problem? Describe these steps in words. Then try to translate those words into python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted a recursive solution, here's a recursive solution using `frozensets` -

```
set_list = [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 50, 60}, {70, 90}, {70, 80}, {1, 2}, {999, 888}]
input_list = set(frozenset(x) for x in set_list)

def merge(data):
    for x in set(data):
        for y in set(data):
            if x == y:
                continue
            if not x.isdisjoint(y):
                data.remove(x)
                data.remove(y)
                data.add(x.union(y))
                return merge(data)
    return data

print(merge(input_list))
```

output -

```
{frozenset({888, 999}), frozenset({80, 90, 70}), frozenset({1, 50, 3, 2, 60})}
```

---

For an example case when a set in `set_list` matches with multiple sets in `output` -

```
set_list = [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 50, 60}, {70, 90}, {70, 80}, {1, 2}, {999, 888}, {888, 2}]
```

output -

```
{frozenset({1, 2, 3, 50, 999, 888, 60}), frozenset({80, 90, 70})}
```

Comment: I wrote something very similar but it gave me an exception telling me that I can't modify a set I am currently iterating over. It didn't occur to me to use set(data) instead of data. I'm sure this trick will be help me down the road. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, might help nevertheless.

```
set_list = [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 50, 60}, {70, 90}, {70, 80}, {1, 2}, {999, 888}]

result = [set_list[0]]
for elem in set_list:
    if not elem.isdisjoint(result[-1]):
        result[-1].update(elem)
    else:
        _updated = False
        for i, set_ in enumerate(result):
            if not elem.isdisjoint(set_):
                result[i].update(elem)
                _updated = True
        if not _updated:
            result.append(elem)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{1, 2, 3, 50, 60}, {80, 90, 70}, {888, 999}]
```

Edit:
As Max Miller pointed out, this does not work for certain inputs, his solution is much more complete.

Comment: This will not work when a new set has an intersection with multiple sets in the `result`. In which case one/more of the sets from `result` needs to be consolidated into one.

Comment: You are right, I think it's fixed now.

Comment: It still needs a consolidation step where you need to merge multiple sets into `result` into one when `elem` has an intersection with multiple sets in `result`. Try with `[{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 50, 60}, {70, 90}, {70, 80}, {1, 2}, {999, 888}, {888, 2}]`, or you can use your current solution recursively on result as well.